# Multi-Class Classification

Tags: python, jupyter, cumsum

The file "Textbook adoption 3 groups.csv" contains information on 119 universities and the goal is to use these data to fit models and make the predictions using the 6 predictors.

Combine the classes of the response variable into two meta classes so that it is NoMore versus others. Publishers want to ID those who might stop using the book to take proactive action.

1. Split the data into training (60%) and validation (40%) datasets. Use the random seed 202.
2. Run Logistic Regression, KNN and Neural Nets models. Report the validation confusion matrix for each of the three models.
3. Compare the error rates of validation sets for the three individual methods.
4. Produce gains and decile lift charts on the validation set using your models and compare their performance..

I've already figured out the code for questions 1 - 3, but I am getting an error with my code when trying to plot the gains and decile lift charts. Specifically, with the "cumulative_positives = validation_results['Actual'].cumsum() / total_positive_instances" line. What am I doing wrong?

```
# Calculating predicted probabilities for each model on the validation set
lr_probs = lr_model.predict_proba(X_validation)[:, 1]
knn_probs = knn_model.predict_proba(X_validation)[:, 1]
nn_probs = nn_model.predict_proba(X_validation)[:, 1]

# Combine the probabilities and the actual target values in a DataFrame
validation_results = pd.DataFrame({
    'Actual': y_validation,
    'LR_Prob': lr_probs,
    'KNN_Prob': knn_probs,
    'NN_Prob': nn_probs})

# Sort the DataFrame by predicted probabilities in descending order
validation_results = validation_results.sort_values(by='LR_Prob', ascending=False)

# Calculate the cumulative gains for each model
total_positive_instances = validation_results['Actual'].sum()
cumulative_positives = validation_results['Actual'].cumsum() / total_positive_instances

# Calculate the decile lift for each model
deciles = np.linspace(10, 100, 10).astype(int)
decile_lifts = []
for decile in deciles:
    threshold_index = len(validation_results) * decile // 100
    decile_lift = validation_results['Actual'].iloc[:threshold_index].mean() / validation_results['Actual'].mean()
    decile_lifts.append(decile_lift)

# Plotting the gains chart
plt.plot(np.linspace(0, 100, len(validation_results)), cumulative_positives, label='Logistic Regression')
plt.xlabel('Percentage of Data')
plt.ylabel('Percentage of Positive Instances Captured')
plt.title('Gains Chart')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# Plotting the decile lift chart
plt.bar(deciles, decile_lifts)
plt.xlabel('Deciles')
plt.ylabel('Decile Lift')
plt.title('Decile Lift Chart')
plt.show()
```

Comment: What's the error message?